# Problema con http://localhost:8080/

Tags: java, tomcat

Estoy realizando proyectos Java EE y al lanzar el servidor tomcat y abrir el navegador constantemente me sale Error 404. Eso me hizo comprobar el localhost 8080 porque todas las direcciones estaban bien y siempre se empeñaba en el Error 404. Al acceder al navegador y escribir localhost:8080 me dice vaya no se puede tener acceso a esta pagina a que se debe que podría hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: Puede que el firewall te esté bloqueando el acceso

Comment: tambien he probado a desbloquear el firewall y sigue apareciendo el 404

Answer (score 2):

El error 404 en Tomcat si es de esta manera:

[image: TomcatError404]

Puede ser cualquier fichero siendo un HTML, JSP o un path a una imagen. Puede ser desde que a donde intente acceder no este bien referenciado. Comprueba si la url esta bien ya que suele ser la solución más común.

**Un ejemplo**, en Eclipse puedes ir a:
(Window >> Show View >> Servers)
Ve a la localización de tu Servidor Tomcat y ver el Overview
Ahí puedes modificar la localización del server y de ahí guardas
Reinicia tu servidor y ve a localhost:8080.

Supondré que en los demás IDE serán pasos parecidos.

Comment: ¿Exactamente que error te aparece, tal cual en la imagen o una pagina en blanco con el error 404? También puede ser si usas Java Servlets te den problemas, que la pagina a la que hace forwarding este mal puesta en código. ¿Haciendo debug no te muestra más info?

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda finalmente funciona bien  he puesto el jdk y el servidor de 0 y lo he referenciado correctamente todo correcto Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: ¿Entonces fue de redirección o algún otro problema de por medio? Me alegra que te haya salido bien.

Comment: si y también como recordatorio por si alguien consulta esto cuidado con dar run sobre el proyecto, dar run on server desde el html, servlet etc.